# How is this javascript expression interpreted?

Tags: javascript

How do the following expressions get parsed and interpreted?

The chrome console does this:

```
> {'foo'}{'bar'}
'bar'
```

and similarly

```
> {a: 'foo'}{b: 'bar'}
'bar'
```

(Obviously whatever is going on here shouldn't be used in real code.)

Comment: `{` start block `'foo'` evaluate string `}` end block, the result of the expression is that of the last block; in your second case `a:` and `b:` are labels for `goto`; sorry, can't elaborate more now.

Comment: why in the second case ar those interpreted as labels and not objects with properties. If I have the expression {b: 'bar'}, it evaluates to itself not to the label

Comment: Neither of those are expressions.

Comment: Those aren't expressions, rather just string literal in a block statement.

Comment: @bhspencer because when the first token in a statement is `{`, that is parsed as the opening of a block of statements, not an object initializer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if something produces a value it's an expression

Comment: @Pointy then why does {b: 'bar'} on its own evaluate to {b: 'bar'}, But when you have {a: 'foo'}{b: 'bar'} it evaluates to "bar"

Comment: @0stone0 I fairly sure they are expressions since they evaluate to values.

Comment: No, they are absolutely definitely not expressions. Keep in mind that what the **console** shows is the "result" of the statement. That's not the same as the evaluated result of an expression; indeed, in `let x = { b: "bar" };`, the value of `x` will not be "bar".

Comment: @Pointy isn't that only because the object syntax "collides" with a block syntax?

Comment: The browser console is really a terrible place to do experiments like this, because the console is not at all designed for that purpose. Write yourself a Node program and see what happens. That's much more reliable.

Comment: @Konrad well yes, but the parser disambiguates by 100% of the time deciding that when a statement starts with `{` it's a block, not an object initializer. It is an ambiguity in the syntax but the parser fixes it deterministically.

Comment: eval is evil I know but `eval("{'foo'}{'bar'}") === 'bar'`. Which I find very interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [AST Explorer](https://astexplorer.net/) to view AST details.

Code 1:

```js
{'foo'}{'bar'}
```

AST:

```json
[
  {
    "type": "BlockStatement",
    "start": 0,
    "end": 7,
    "body": [
      {
        "type": "ExpressionStatement",
        "start": 1,
        "end": 6,
        "expression": {
          "type": "Literal",
          "start": 1,
          "end": 6,
          "value": "foo",
          "raw": "'foo'"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "BlockStatement",
    "start": 7,
    "end": 14,
    "body": [
      {
        "type": "ExpressionStatement",
        "start": 8,
        "end": 13,
        "expression": {
          "type": "Literal",
          "start": 8,
          "end": 13,
          "value": "bar",
          "raw": "'bar'"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So it means two blocks.

Code 2:

```js
{a: 'foo'}{b: 'bar'}
```

AST:

```json
[
  {
    "type": "BlockStatement",
    "start": 0,
    "end": 10,
    "body": [
      {
        "type": "LabeledStatement",
        "start": 1,
        "end": 9,
        "body": {
          "type": "ExpressionStatement",
          "start": 4,
          "end": 9,
          "expression": {
            "type": "Literal",
            "start": 4,
            "end": 9,
            "value": "foo",
            "raw": "'foo'"
          }
        },
        "label": {
          "type": "Identifier",
          "start": 1,
          "end": 2,
          "name": "a"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "BlockStatement",
    "start": 10,
    "end": 20,
    "body": [
      {
        "type": "LabeledStatement",
        "start": 11,
        "end": 19,
        "body": {
          "type": "ExpressionStatement",
          "start": 14,
          "end": 19,
          "expression": {
            "type": "Literal",
            "start": 14,
            "end": 19,
            "value": "bar",
            "raw": "'bar'"
          }
        },
        "label": {
          "type": "Identifier",
          "start": 11,
          "end": 12,
          "name": "b"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So it means two blocks with two [labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

Comment: That is the only true answer IMO

Answer (score 0):

The 1st statement could be rewritten as

```
{
  'foo';
}
{
  'bar';
}
```

That is, two separate block statements, each containing a constant string literal. The result is the last expression evaluated while interpreting this code, which is `'bar'`.

The second statement can be similarly rewritten as

```
{
  a: 'foo';
}
{
  b: 'bar';
}
```

Where `a` and `b` are [labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label), which can be used for limited jumps in code (typically to exit inner loops in a nested loop). Again, this evaluates to `'bar'`. While this second statement looks somewhat similar to an object literal, this is not the case. Note that `> {b: 'bar', a: 'foo'}` results in a syntax error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'

As [Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy) has observed in comments, when the interpreter encounters a statement that begins with `{`, which could belong to *either* an object literal or a code-block, it interprets it as a code block, consistently. Is this true for all spec-compliant parsers? Let us assume that the [js grammar contributed to Antlr4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/javascript/javascript/JavaScriptParser.g4) is correct (according to comments, it was updated for ES2020). In Antlr4, whatever rule is specified first has priority over later rules. We find that (copying and pasting the relevant rules from the linked grammar):

```
program
    : HashBangLine? sourceElements? EOF
    ;

sourceElement
    : statement
    ;

statement
    : block
    | variableStatement
    | importStatement
    | exportStatement
    | emptyStatement_
    | classDeclaration
    | functionDeclaration
    | expressionStatement
    | ifStatement
    | iterationStatement
    | continueStatement
    | breakStatement
    | returnStatement
    | yieldStatement
    | withStatement
    | labelledStatement
    | switchStatement
    | throwStatement
    | tryStatement
    | debuggerStatement
    ;

expressionStatement
    : {this.notOpenBraceAndNotFunction()}? expressionSequence eos
    ;

expressionSequence
    : singleExpression (',' singleExpression)*
    ;

singleExpression
# ...snipped many lines...
    | objectLiteral                # ObjectLiteralExpression
    | '(' expressionSequence ')'   # ParenthesizedExpression
    ;
```

Therefore, assuming that this grammar is correct, JS will **always** interpret opening `{`s as blocks, because `block` appears much earlier in `statement` than `expressionStatement` (which leads to `objectLiteral` via `expressionSequences`->`singleExpression`->`objectLiteral`).

Comment: Neither are expressions however.

Comment: can you explain why {b: 'bar'} on its own evaluates to {b: 'bar'} and not 'bar'?

Comment: @Pointy OP was referring to them as expressions, and they are understandable as such using common English. Yes, in a strict language sense they are not (except in that a JS console evaluates them to values). Rewriting to use the correct programming term, "Statement".

Comment: @tucuxi yea I know what you mean and yes in normal conversation that's fine, but this is intended to be a place for authoritative information. Personally I'm not strict with terminology in general but I try to keep answers pretty much accurate.